# String ordering in Lua

Tags: string, character-encoding, lua

I'm reading [Programming in Lua, 1st edition](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) (yup, I know it's a bit outdated), and in the [section 3.2](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.2.html) (about relational operators), the author says:

> For instance, with the European Latin-1 locale, we have "acai" < "açaí" < "acorde".

I don't get it. For me, it's OK to have `"acai" < "açaí"`, but why is `"açaí" < "acorde"`?

AFAIK ([and wikipedia seems to confirm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout)), `"c" < "ç"`, or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing it's an error in the book. String sorting is letter by letter, so `"acai" < "açaí" < "acorde"` is equivalent to `'c' < 'ç' < 'c'`, which is nonsensical.

Comment: I thought the same thing when I read this part of the book and I have third edition.

Comment: Which "European Latin-1 locale"? There are many...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reference a code page, which maps codepoints to characters. Certainly codepoints, being a finite set of non-negative integers, are well-ordered, distinct entities. However, that is not what characters are about.

Characters have a [collation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation) order, which is a partial ordering: Characters can be "equal" but not the same. Collation is a user-valued concept that varies by locale (and over time).

Strings are even more complicated because some character sets (e.g. Unicode) can have combining characters. That allows a "character" to be represented as a single character or as a base character followed by the combining characters. For example, "ä" vs "a¨". Since they represent the same conceptual character they should be considered even more equal than "ä" vs "a".

In Spanish, "ch", "rr" and "ll" used to be letters in the alphabet and words were ordered accordingly; Now, they are not but "ñ" still is.

Similarly, in the past it was not uncommon for English-speakers to sort surnames beginning with "Mc" and "Mac" after others beginning with "M".

Software libraries have to deal with such things because that's what users want. Thankfully, some of the older conventions have fallen from use.

---

So, a locale could very well have collation rules that result in "acai" < "açaí" < "acorde" if "c" has the same sort order as "ç" but "i" comes before "í". This case seems strange though the possibility in general requires our code to allow it.

Answer (score 8):

In the third edition of PiL, this statement has been modified:

> For instance, with a Portuguese Latin-1 locale, we have `"acai"<"açaí"<"acorde"`.

So the locale needs to be set to Portuguese Latin-1 accordingly:

```
print("acai" < "açaí")
print("açaí" < "acorde")

print(os.setlocale("pt_PT"))

print("acai" < "açaí")
print("açaí" < "acorde")
```

On [ideone](http://ideone.com/KjZqsx), the result is:

```
true
false
pt_PT.iso88591
false
true
```

But the order of `"acai"` and `"açaí"` seems to be different from the book now.

Comment: OK. That is the fact, but it doesn't explain such behaviour. I mean, why is `"acai" < "açaí"` and `"açaí" < "acorde"`? As @Kamiccolo pointed out in a comment, [lvm.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lvm.c.html#l_strcmp) uses the strcoll() function to compare the strings, so it looks like the diacritics may not be relevant in the comparison.

Comment: @yu @stu `"açaí" < "acorde"` is not true (as highlighted by @YuHao). Indeed, I also believe that there is a typo in the book. It should be written that: `"acai"<"acorde"<"açaí"`